# How to echo multiple images from json using PHP

Tags: php, json, image, slider, gallery

I'm very new to php/json so please bare with me.  I'm building a real estate website and would like to display images in a gallery or slideshow.  I'm having issues figuring out how to access more than one image at a time.

json looks like this:

```
[{
"Media": [ { "MediaULR": "https://dvvjkgh94f2v6.cloudfront.net/62e30b5c/33639334/83dcefb7.jpeg",
             "ShortDescription": "Infinity edge pool and spa." },
              "MediaULR": "https://dvvjkgh94f2v6.cloudfront.net/62e30b5c/33639334/7d65264f.jpeg",
             "ShortDescription": "Golf on four awarding-winning courses." }] 
}]
```

I can access this first image using:

```
<?php foreach($mls as $mls): ?>
<!-- Image --><img src="<?php echo $mls->Media[0]->MediaURL; ?>"> 
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

How do I go about displaying both images?  The Media[0] is selecting the first image.  I can't simply create a new echo with [1] because there could be countless images.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Loop through the Media array.

Comment: In your controller `$mls = jsonOrSomething['Media']`. However you can do the following as well:`foreach($mls['Media'] as $item){ echo $item->MediaULR; }`

Comment: Thanks!  If anyone is interested here is the code that got it to work:

Comment: <?php foreach($mls->Media as $jmedia) echo '<img src="'.$jmedia->MediaURL.'";>'?>

Comment: If you made it work you should add it as a proper answer below. Then it can receive upvotes and be found in searches. That doesn't happen if you just put it in the comments. Answering your own question is encouraged :-)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks! If anyone is interested here is the code that got it to work:

```
<?php foreach($mls->Media as $jmedia) echo '<img src="'.$jmedia->MediaURL.'";>'?>
```